# How do I embed an SVG image inside another SVG image using Batik svggen?

Tags: java, svg, graphics2d, batik

I am programatically generating a large image using the Java Graphics2D related libraries. I am using the SVGGraphics2D class from Batik to allow rendering to SVG.

My challenge is that I have a set of icons that are already in SVG format that I want to embed into the larger image.

Based on the Batik documents I understand how to bring the icon SVG files into the Graphics2D environment using an ImageTranscoder. However this process is rasterizing the SVG files and turning them into a BufferedImage.

The result is that when I render the main image at larger dimensions, the icons look horrible while the rest of the image is crisp.

Is there a way to embed an SVG image using SVGGraphics2D without rasterizing it first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an SVG `<image>` element using [createElementNS](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/dom/svg/SVGDOMImplementation.html#createElementNS%28org.apache.batik.dom.AbstractDocument,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), set the xlink:href attribute using [setAttributeNS](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/dom/AbstractElement.html#setAttributeNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to where your SVG icons are hosted and the x, y, width and height attributes using [setAttribute](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/dom/AbstractElement.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I don't think this will work for my situation. I am using the SVGGraphics2D class to create the SVG image, I am not working with the DOM model directly.